# Global shortcut of Lightshot under Wine

Tags: debian, wine

I installed Lightshot in Wine but I couldn't get the `PrintScr` button to work at all.
It is not detected by Lightshot.

How to go about fixing this? Is a keymap necessary?
Maybe the PrintScr keycode is not the same between debian and wine?

Comment: Please don't post your solution in the question, post it as an answer using the **Post Your Answer** button below. This way you'll be able to get more reputation from upvotes and mark the answer as accepted. This will mark the question as resolved, which will make it easier to find for other people facing the same issue.

Comment: Done, I posted the solution below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved the issue using `xdotool`

```
sudo apt install xdotool

xdotool key --window $( xdotool search --name Lightshot ) "Print"
```

I put the code inside lightshot.sh then assigned a custom shortcut (PrintScr) to it in KDE Custom Shortcuts